# Normalizing Data for thickness

Tags: statistics

Math is not my strong point and I am struggling with trying to figure out how to solve the following problem...any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated!

I'm looking to normalize this data for thickness. I want to determine how long it takes different materials to reach a certain temperature (24 degrees) and adjust for thickness as they will not all have the exact same thickness! Basically I want to see is one sample was better than the others (the longer time to temp the better!) but I'm not sure how the thickness is affecting the results.

Sample A: Thickness is .044" Time to temp was 10.9sec
 Sample B: Thickness is .05" Time to temp was 11.55sec
 Sample C: Thickness is .05" Time to temp was 11.2sec
 Sample D: Thickness is .048" Time to temp was 11.5sec
 Sample E: Thickness is .049" Time to temp was 11.75sec

Comment: "Different materials"? As in, different chemical compounds? Why would you expect to be able to say anything in this case? If it is the same compound, how would you expect the temperature to be related to thickness? The thicker the material, the longer it takes to reach the  temperature? Do you expect this to be linear (i.e., if the thickness is doubled, will the time double as well)?

Answer (score 1):

The time it takes to reach a certain temperature will vary if the materials of the sample are all different.